# I have an issue with initializing Jquery File upload plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, blueimp

I'm using this plugin for my upload in backbone, however, I have to submit 2 times before uploading.
When I chose my file for the first time it seems like the fileupload function doesnt execute, and then when I chose a second time it will execute.

It seems like very stupid but I don't get where i'm wrong..

Here's the backbone part:

```
form_submit: function(e){

    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    add: function (e, data) {


        // Automatically upload the file once it is added to the queue
        var jqXHR = data.submit();
    },
    progress: function(e, data){
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
        'width',
        progress + '%'
        );
        if (progress == 100) {
        var message = "<font color=green>Fichier uploadé !</font>";
        var info = document.getElementById("info");
        info.innerHTML=message;
        }
    }
    });
}
```

and here's my html part if it can helps:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="maj-container">
    <script type="text/template" id="maj-template">
      <div class="file-input-wrapper" id="file-group">
    <button class="btn-file-input" id="btn-file">Choisir un fichier</button>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" id="fileupload" multiple />
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div id="progress" class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="info" style="margin-top:30px"></div>
    </script>
  </form>
```

EDIT: 
Ok so I made some research and apparently this error occurs because I don't initialize the plugin.
So I tried to initialize it by doing $('#fileupload').fileupload(); but It doesn't work.
I tried to place it in differents places: at the beginning of the form_submit function, in the render:

```
render: function(){
    var template = _.template(this.template.html());
    this.$el.html(template({ m : this.model.toJSON()}));
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: '/rest/maj/',
    sequentialUploads: true
    });
    return this;
},
```

I tried also in the initialize:

```
initialize : function(options) {

        $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: '/rest/maj/',
    sequentialUploads: true
    });
    this.router = options.router;
    this.render();


},
```

But nothing works.. it still doesn't fire at first time.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below and mark it "accepted" as soon as allowed.  Do not post the solution within your question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I solved my issue: I just had to put the fileupload function in $(document).ready(function() like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var router = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();

$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    url: '/rest/maj/',
    //acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(tar|tgz|tar.gz)$/i,
    //maxFileSize: 20000000,  // 20 MB

    add: function (e, data) {
        var acceptFileTypes = /^application\/(tar|tgz|tar.gz|gzip|x-tar)$/i;
        alert(data.files[0]['type']); // Pour vérifier la syntaxe de l'extension
        //alert(data.files[0]['size']); Pour vérifier la taille du fichier
        if(data.files[0]['type'].length && !acceptFileTypes.test(data.files[0]['type'])) { //si le type ne correspond pas à ceux définits dans acceptFileTypes
        $('#info').append('<font color=red><b>Mauvaise extension</b></font><br/><br/>Extensions valides : <b>(tar|tgz|tar.gz)</b>');

        }
        else if(data.files[0]['size'] > 20000000) { //si la taille du fichier dépasse 20 MB
        $('#info').append('<font color=red><b>La taille du fichier doit etre inférieure à 20 MO</b></font>');   

        }
        else {

        var jqXHR = data.submit(); //upload le fichier direct après qu'on l'ai choisi
        }
    },
    progress: function(e, data){
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10); // calcule l'avancement de l'upload et l'affiche dans la bar progress
        $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
        'width',
        progress + '%'
        );
        if (progress == 100) {
        $('#info').append('<font color=green><b>Fichier uploadé !</b></font>');
        }
    }

});


});
```